# A simple way to save a file version to a child folder and generate/increment a log?

Tags: tortoisesvn, versioning, tortoisehg, tortoisegit

I looked to TortoiseSVN and TortoiseHG... bit too much for me and I don't want to setup a structure where the files will be saved. All I want is:

When saving a file, first saves the file.

Then if there isn't in file's folder a sub-folder called "History", it creates it.
Then Copies the file to "History" and gives it the first available number suffix as "_[version]".

Then, if is no txt file, in the file's folder, called "[filename].[extension]_Notes.txt", it creates it and adds a line with: 
Version: [version] " of the " [filename] " saved at: " [date]

Now how would this run from any application? Dunno. Maybe have a button in the file save dialog?

I'm asking this because I'm just one guy working and not on huge projects and 99% of the time I would just like to have a localized versioning, set on a local sub-folder and a log to track the versions and dates.

Is this super easy with Tortoise and I'm being a mule?

Cheers

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: you described **ancient** versioning. In my solo-work I'll prefer TortoiseSVN (with locally accessed repository) or TortoiseHG for this task

Comment: Well, might be ancient to you, sir. But feels just right to me. I don't need to setup a server or repository. Just on-the-fly create a backup, anywhere...

Do you recommend any guide for solo users?

thanks

Comment: Setup repository is one-click action in Tortoises. With TortoiseSVN+EditPlus I can have Save+Auto-commit file, f.e.

Comment: Just so I'm clear. I'm not doing code. I want to use this for 3D scene files, heavy images, etc.
This is what I saw at a studio to save:
http://i.imgur.com/dFQ1OP1.png
History folder with copies. An outside *.txt gives the details. I always reference to the same file location which is always the most up to date and if I have any issues I go to the history folder. I don't want to upload files to the internet. Also how would Tortoise deal with binary files? Maybe the issue is that I haven't seen it in action. Probably would be much clear after that.
Cheers

Comment: "Code or not code" - doesn't matter at all. You just have all, full (linear) history with dates and comments for every stored change. Repository can (in case of HG - must) be pure local

Comment: Used Git and TortoiseHG today. I have no interest in having to make a lot of repository folders... Sure it will be handy on long projects, but to version a file locally, simply create a duplicate of the file and hide the old version this is a cannon to kill a fly. Maybe what I'm looking for is a Batch File? Cheers

Comment: TortoiseSVN and **one** common Subversion-repository for all files?

Comment: And how do you make a single repository that can do version control for any file anywhere? whenever I try to make a repository it even tells me the folder must be empty...

Comment: Ok so with SVN you "Import" files from anywhere to the repository, unlike HG where the files have to be under a local repository.

Comment: Oh but then I have to do this to be able to commit...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943665/how-to-update-a-file-in-svn

Comment: 1. Create repo in special empty folder 2. `svn import PATH/TO/FILE file:///REPO/DIR/FOR/FILE` (dir per file) 3. `svn co -f file:///REPO/DIR/FOR/FILE PATH/TO/` - Every old directory with file now is WC of special part of common repository

Comment: Well, thanks for the continous feedback. But this is just not good for wildcard versioning. With SVN I have to checkout after import to then be able to commit new versions. So I end up with 3 files, the original, the repository one and the checkout folder one... Not really what I wanted...  Cheers

Comment: You have only repository (not file, but tree - with **all**) files and **1** file in WC - you checkout on top of your existing imported file

Comment: But I can't import files. Just folders. So, no wildcards.
If I'm already in a very organized structure. Sure any of them will be great and I'll be using them. What I wanted was for also files outside a project structure. And the **ancient** solution would fit perfectly ;)

Comment: `svn help import` "import: Commit an unversioned **file or tree** into the repository"

Comment: When you write click a file this is what you see: http://snag.gy/Yexq8.jpg  Plus, if I get to import single files, by the time I'm on my 50th, I'll have a to look for it in a long checkout list of all the wildcard/unstructured files I have been importing. I'm converted to Version Control, you made it! But only for project folders, for wildcard backups/versions, no me gusta I would prefer the *ancient* solution. Thanks